# script to filter latest version of rpm from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I have got a file which contain  thousand's of rpm's with  different version as mentioned below.I need to pick latest version and store it in a file..

```
yum-rhn-plugin-0.9.1-43.el6.noarch
yum-rhn-plugin-0.9.1-50.el6.noarch
yum-utils-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch
yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch
zd1211-firmware-1.4-4.el6.noarch
zip-3.0-1.el6.x86_64
zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64
```

Target file should contain only following rpm's..

```
yum-rhn-plugin-0.9.1-50.el6.noarch
yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch
zd1211-firmware-1.4-4.el6.noarch
zip-3.0-1.el6.x86_64
zlib-1.2.3-29.el6.x86_64
```

Please let me know any script/command suitable for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -ng file | tr '\n' ' ' | ruby -ne 'puts $_.split.group_by{|x|x[/^[^.]+-?[^\d.-]/]}.map{|k,v|v.last}'
```